# how can i update/upgrade a vsi with slcli?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a list of vsi's created in my account. Now I need to update the configuration, especially the CPU or Memory. When I try to use slcli vs upgrade I see the correct options that I want to use, but If I try I see:
This action will incur charges on your account. Continue? [y/N]: y
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): A price was not submitted for Computing Instance and the current product #857 is not valid for the preset configuration.

This lets me assume that I probably have to create a kind of order? But how should I modify an existing order? I do not want a new order, but want to modify an existing order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your vs was created with a flavor and you are upgrading using cpu and ram separately.

There are to ways to upgrade a vs:

1. Using flavors, e.g. B1_1X4X25 (1 cpu, 4 GB RAM, 25 GB first disk)
2. Using cpu, ram separately.

To know if the vs was created with a flavor, run the following command:

```
slcli --format json call-api Virtual_Guest getObject --mask=mask[billingItem[id,orderItem[id,preset]]] --id=11111
```

Replace the "11111" data with your vs id.

If the vs has preset data use flavor option to upgrade your vs if it does not have use cpu and ram separately.

To know the valid options to upgrade the vs you can use the below slcli command:

```
slcli virtual upgrade --help
```

**1. To upgrade a vs with flavor, use the following slcli command:**

```
slcli virtual upgrade --flavor B1_2X4X25 11111
```

Replace the "11111" data with your vs id.

**2. To upgrade a vs with cpu, ram separately use the following slcli command:**

```
slcli virtual upgrade --cpu 2 --memory 2048 11111
```

To get all the items available to upgrade your vs, you can use the below slcli command:

```
slcli virtual create-options
```

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. You are right, i did the configuration with flavors. your first command does not work, as the --mask option is not accepted. But I was able to upgrade my instances with the --flavor option. One more question: How can I automatically accept the question when using the command? There is this question that this action will incur charges which I have to answer. Is there a force option ? or something where i can configure the "yes"?

Comment: Ok, seems that I found a solution on that:

yes | slcli virtual upgrade --flavor B1_2X4X25 11111

this will pipe the y into the question. Which leads to the desired result.

Comment: You can to add `-y` or `--really` after `slcli` to confirm prompt actions, I recommend you run `slcli --help` to see all available options.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution for your request. The first slcli command is working for me. I suggest you to update your slcli with the last version.

Comment: @AlbertCamacho I tried to use something like the -y switch, but it seems that there is no such switch. I am using slcli 5.6.4, which should be the actual version when I look at the sources on github. Or do you have a different version of slcli?

Comment: I have the same slcli version, try with `slcli -y virtual upgrade --flavor B1_2X4X25 111111`, if the prompt is still displayed then I recommend you open an issue here https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues for further investigation, don't forget provide information like the OS of your environment

Comment: On the slcli when an upgrade is accepted it doesn't returns any value, https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/CLI/virt/upgrade.py. to check if upgrade is running it is recommended to see the active transaction with `slcli virtual detail 11111` or `slcli call-api Virtual_Guest --id=111111 getActiveTransactions`